# How can Tristran believe this about his adopted mother?

Tags: neil-gaiman, stardust

Near the beginning of *Stardust*, Tristran Thorn is not allowed to go to a Faerie Market, presumably because his birth mother is from Faerie and his parents are worried about losing him. We then hear that:

> His younger sister, Louisa, **six months his junior**, was, however, allowed to go to the market, and this was a source of great ranklement to the boy...

At the end of the book, Tristran learns the truth:

> Tristran raised the matter that had been vexing him, which was the question of his birth. His father answered him as honestly as he was able to during the long walk back to the farmhouse...
>
> And then they were at Tristran's old home, where his sister waited for him, and there was a steaming breakfast on the stove and on the table, prepared for him, lovingly, by the woman he had always believed to be his mother.

Given the obvious biological difficulties with having a sister six months his junior, does any version of the story give an explicit explanation for why he wouldn't have known this all along? (Beyond the default explanation that he's generally kind of an unobservant doofus.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked my good friend Neil Gaiman about this.

Evidently it was an *wholly intentional* observation. Basically we're supposed to smack our foreheads at the enormity of [Tristran's cluelessness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135329/how-can-tristran-believe-this-about-his-adopted-mother#comment343311_135329).

> **Q.** *If Tristan Thorn thought Daisy was his **biological** mother, how could Louisa have been "six months his junior"?*
>
> **Gaiman.** *Yes. That's sort of the point.*
>
> <sub><sup>[via Twitter](https://twitter.com/neilhimself/status/758797381865385984)</sup></sub>